# how to enable db4 support in PHP7 (SuSE Leap 15.0)

Tags: php-7, opensuse, berkeley-db

I recently upgrade to SuSE Leap 15 and PHP7. everything works fine, but there is no db4 support in PHP7, more generally only handlers cdb, ini and flatfile are availible. commandline utilitys are installed.

Is there any way to activate db4 handler in PHP7 without recompiling PHP7?

DBA handlers shown by the following php code:

cdb: 0.75
cdb_make: 0.75
inifile: 1.0
flatfile: 1.0

```
<?php

echo "Available DBA handlers:\n";
foreach (dba_handlers(true) as $handler_name => $handler_version) {
  // clean the versions
  $handler_version = str_replace('$', '', $handler_version);
  echo " - $handler_name: $handler_version\n\r";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to activate berkdb support without recompiliation of PHP, if its not compiled in.

The best way is to file a bug for the distribution in use, in my case SuSE Leap 15, and ask for re-enabeling.

e.g. https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1108554 was fixed within 2 days.